# Как исправить шаблон пагинации в laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Добрый день знатоки laravel. Дошёл до темы пагинации в изучении данного вопроса и схватил стопор. Хоть в документации про пагинацию в ларавель было сказано что работа с ней - это глоток свежего воздуха по сравнению с другими фреймворками, я такого ощущения не ощутил. Вот как всё было Создал контролер:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller {

  public function show() {
    return view('user.data', ['users' => User::paginate(2)]);
  }
}
```

И в представлении вида:

```
<ul>
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Решил глянуть, а что собственно у меня на страничке происходить. После созерцания таковой у меня буквально глаза на лоб вылезли:[image: Ошибка laravel]

Да безусловно метод пагинейт отработал как надо и вывел 2 записи как от него и ожидалось. Но какого лешия помимо этого вывелось ещё чёрт знает что, вот чём главный вопрос. Причём когда в контролере у меня присутвовала запись вида: `'users' => DB::table('users')->simplePaginate(2)` всё работало исправно и выводились две ссылки « Previous и Next ». Но в современных реалиях однако мало только двух ссылок, требуется более точная деталиция и поэтому смекнув так я пошёл дальше, но увы встретил на своём пути данное безобразие. Мне нужны были ссылки как числа, и да они есть ниже если пролистать страницу, но накой, ещё раз спрашиваю, чёрт помимо них ещё хрен пойми что. Помниться в старой версии (это я узнал из видео, просмотренного накануне) не было такой беды. Если кто сталкивался с данной ошибкой присоветуйте способы её решения.

Comment: А у Вас стили какие-то подключены вообще? Потому что согласно документации `By default, the HTML generated by the paginator is compatible with the Tailwind CSS framework; however, Bootstrap pagination support is also available.`, а судя по тому как у Вас выглядит шаблон, у Вас просто голый html.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать свой шаблон. Варианты подключения:

1. Скопировать стандартный шаблон `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` и править его.
2. `{{ $paginator->links('view.name') }}`
3. 

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Providers;
 
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
 
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::defaultView('view-name');
 
        Paginator::defaultSimpleView('view-name');
    }
}
```

См. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: В документации которую я читал всё было точно так как вы здесь написали. Но после прочтения документации я ненашёл папку Providers, и решил спросить здесь. А команду ``` php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination``` выполнил и в папке views появилась папка с шаблонами. После изучения вашего ответа папка providers появилась а в ней класс с методом boot, туда я и вставил всё указанное содержимое. Изменил имена представлений на user.data. Сначало написал с расширением и получилось user.data.blade.php, но вспомнил что в контролере пишеться без него и убрал.

Comment: В представлении тоже вставил user.data и получилось {{ $users->links('user.data') }}. Запустил но почему-то теперь получил ошибку: "Undefined variable $users". Изменил $users на $paginator и снова получил ошибку: "Undefined variable $paginator". Тогда я решил оставить всё как было, а именно в представление вставил строку {{ $paginator->links('view.name') }}, а в методе boot вернул названия представлений как в вашем ответе:

Comment: ```Paginator::defaultView('view-name');
         Paginator::defaultSimpleView('view-name');```, но почему-то ошибка не ушла. Очень странно всё это ведь действую согласно документации, а ничего не получается, даже обидно.

Comment: @ПавелБулин У меня стоит третий вариант в проекте... работает `Paginator::defaultView('bootstrap-5.pagination');`.

Comment: А какая у вас версия laravel? У меня в девятой появляется ошибка вида: "View [bootstrap-5.pagination] not found."

Comment: Тоже 9. `bootstrap-5.pagination` это у меня свой файл с шаблоном в по адресу `\resources\views\bootstrap-5\pagination.blade.php`

Comment: Положил по указаному пути файл bootstrap-5 и стало отображаться без этих гигантских стрелок. Но ссылки на странице выводяться списком. Не то что мне нужно. Жаль в коментарииях нельзя приложить скриншот. Вообщем я умываю руки! Записал себе что данный метод не работает. Спасибо за поддержку

Answer (score 0):

Проблему на 10 версии решил добавлением стоки в файл tailwind.config.js в массив content

```
'./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
```